# Enable WASP server in debug mode

Tags: wasp

I need to enable debug mode in a **WASP** server. Where I can setup or find the remote debug port of a WASP server? Also need to find out the way to tail the log file. I tried tomcat command but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the debug port number from the `server.sh` file. Go to the wasp folder of your server and inside the bin folder the `server.sh file` will be there.
In order to run the server in debug mode kill all the processes in your wasp server by
`killall -9 java` command.

Restart the server using following command

```
./serverstart.sh -debug > output.log 2>&1 &
```

Log file is created inside the bin folder, `output.log`.

Tail the log file using following command.

```
tail -f output.log
```